# Is there a way to find out why it gave me the message "Victory conditions failed"?

Tags: rome-total-war

Everything was fine, I've even occupied a new settlement when all of a sudden it displayed the message "Victory conditions failed". I don't have any idea why (there were enough turns until the game would have ended, so this is not the case).

Answer (score 1):

If you are playing Short campaign your enemy probably reached its own victory condition before you did. It could also be a bug in vanilla RTW.

Check the victory conditions here:
http://rtw.heavengames.com/rtw/mods/tutorials/win_conditions/index.shtml

Answer (score 1):

sounds to me as if someone else beat you to victory.

If i recall, in vanilla this would usually be the egyptians who performed the best - on a short campaign anyway